# Dynamic module import in React Native Expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

If my **React Native** Expo app (running in Expo Go app) currently does an `import/from`

```
import Foo, {Bar} from "foo";
```

How can it be converted to be imported dynamically, where it is imported only when a certain condition is met, such as when `hello === "world"`?

Doing the following causes it to crash with error `non-std C++ exception`.

```
if (hello === "world") {
    import Foo, {Bar} from "foo";
}
```

Tried this alternative and it still crashes with `non-std C++ exception`:

```
if (hello === "world") {
    const Foo = import('foo')
    const Bar = Foo.Bar
}
```

Comment: Imports are not meant to be dynamic (even though I think some libraries let you do that, I'm not sure). Can you detail why you want to do that?

Comment: @FTW On certain devices that the app can be installed to, importing the library will crash the app due to unsupported features being imported. One way to avoid this is to first check whether the device can support the features, then perform the imports.

Comment: Fair enough, try using require() instead?

Comment: You can use platform specific extensions https://reactnative.dev/docs/platform-specific-code#platform-specific-extensions